# Tela Introdutoria App

Tags: android

Ola gostaria de uma luz de como posso estar fazendo uma tela com um tour deste exemplo .[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2428

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/198